# When calculating the space for each direction when the grid size is multiply by 1.5 the directions are wrong why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If the grid is 10x10 or 23x7 it's working fine but when the grid have 1.5 spaces between the cubes the directions sometimes are wrong.

This is the grid script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GridGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gridBlock;
    public int gridWidth = 10;
    public int gridHeight = 10;
    public GameObject[] allBlocks;

    private GameObject[] wallsParents = new GameObject[4];

    void Start()
    {
        wallsParents[0] = GameObject.Find("Top Wall");
        wallsParents[1] = GameObject.Find("Left Wall");
        wallsParents[2] = GameObject.Find("Right Wall");
        wallsParents[3] = GameObject.Find("Bottom Wall");

        GenerateGrid();
        allBlocks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blocks");

        var findpath = GetComponent<PathFinder>();
        findpath.FindPath();
    }

    public void AutoGenerateGrid()
    {
        allBlocks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blocks");

        for (int i = 0; i < allBlocks.Length; i++)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(allBlocks[i]);
        }

        var end = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("End");
        DestroyImmediate(end);

        GenerateGrid();
        allBlocks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Blocks");

        var findpath = GetComponent<PathFinder>();
        findpath.FindPath();
    }

    public void GenerateGrid()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < gridHeight; z++)
            {
                GameObject block = Instantiate(gridBlock, Vector3.zero, gridBlock.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                block.transform.parent = transform;
                block.transform.name = "Block";
                block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * 1.5f, 0, z * 1.5f);
                block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(241, 255, 0, 255);

                if (x == 0)//TOP
                {
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[0].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "TopWall";
                    block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                }
                else if (z == 0)//LEFT
                {
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[1].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "LeftWall";
                    block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                }
                else if (z == gridHeight - 1)//RIGHT
                {
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[2].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "RightWall";
                    block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                }

                else if (x == gridWidth - 1)//BOTTOM
                {
                    block.transform.parent = wallsParents[3].transform;
                    block.transform.name = "BottomWall";
                    block.transform.tag = "Blocks";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On this line i'm adding the spaces between the cubes:

```
block.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * 1.5f, 0, z * 1.5f);
```

Then in another script i'm trying to find what directions next are possible to move to.

```
private void Directions()
    {
        GridGenerator gridgenerator = GetComponent<GridGenerator>();
        Vector3 playerPosition;
        playerPosition = player.localPosition;

        if (playerPosition.x > 0)
        {
            // can go left
            possibleDirections[0] = "Can go left";
        }
        else
        {
            possibleDirections[0] = "Can't go left";
        }

        if (playerPosition.x + 1 < gridgenerator.gridWidth * 1.5f)
        {
            // can go right
            possibleDirections[1] = "Can go right";
        }
        else
        {
            possibleDirections[1] = "Can't go right";
        }

        if (playerPosition.z > 0)
        {
            // can go backward
            possibleDirections[2] = "Can go backward";
        }
        else
        {
            possibleDirections[2] = "Can't go backward";
        }

        if (playerPosition.z + 1 < gridgenerator.gridHeight * 1.5f)
        {
            // can go backward
            possibleDirections[3] = "Can go forward";
        }
        else
        {
            possibleDirections[3] = "Can't go forward";
        }
    }
```

possibleDirections is array string type

When the grid size is 10x10 without spaces between cubes this two lines:

```
if (playerPosition.x + 1 < gridgenerator.gridWidth * 1.5f)
if (playerPosition.z + 1 < gridgenerator.gridHeight * 1.5f)
```

Was:

```
if (playerPosition.x + 1 < gridgenerator.gridWidth)
if (playerPosition.z + 1 < gridgenerator.gridHeight)
```

But when i added the spaces between the cubes i tried to add to the gridgenerator.gridWidth and gridgenerator.gridHeight the * 1.5

But it didn't work so i tried also:

```
if (playerPosition.x + 1 < gridgenerator.gridWidth * (1 + 1.5))
if (playerPosition.z + 1 < gridgenerator.gridHeight * (1 + 1.5))
```

1 is the cube width and 1.5 is the space. But this is not working good either.

In the screenshot the player is in the top left corner facing up(forward)
He can't move forward but in the inspector it says "Can go forward" And should be "Can't go forward"

It only happens when there are spaces between the cubes.

[image: Grid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

> `if (playerPosition.x + 1 < gridgenerator.gridWidth * 1.5f)`

Your `gridWidth` variable stores the *number of cubes*, not their *collective spacing.*  You have 10 cubes representing move spaces, determining the out-of-bounds this value should remain constant (it's still only 10 cubes, even if they're spaced with a half-block worth of space between them).

You need to convert from the player's *scene location* (`transform.position.x`) to a board space location (likely dividing by the same multiplier used to space the cubes out).

Alternatively, the "this makes my soul cry" solution of doing this:

`if (playerPosition.x + 1.5f < gridgenerator.gridWidth * 1.5f)`

Because the next cube is 1.5 *scene units* away, not 1.  And this makes my soul cry because it makes your code full of hard-coded `1.5f` multipliers and offsets rather than keeping such things to a single, fixed, constant value stored Elsewhere and used sparingly.

Related:

> `possibleDirections[0] = "Can go left";`

Why are you using [stringly typed](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) things? There are values called booleans for a reason...